# Pasting into several textboxes simultaneously

Tags: javascript, paste

I created a javascript add-on for Firefox which manipulates clipboard and pastes certain text into any textbox on the webpage.
On this webpage I have several textboxes with the same ID.

Now I need to paste text into all these textboxes simultaneously. For example, if I paste something into the first (or any other) textbox it will be automatically pasted into all other textboxes.

I didn't find any examples or experiences with that in the internet. So, I will be happy to any suggestions/solutions.

Comment: #id's should be unique. You could try to add a class instead or if you want to populate all the textboxes on the page you could select the texboxes with: `document.querySelectorAll("input:text");` or even better, use JQuery and use `$('input')` to select all input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Several textboxes? Considering everything is of `<input type="text" />`, you can use:

```
// Select all the textboxes.
textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input:text");
// Iterate each of them.
for (i in textBoxes) {
  // Add a value for each.
  textBoxes[i].value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a class on each of the input.

```
    <input class="myClass" type="text" id="selector">
    <input class="myClass" class="" type="text" id="selector">
    <input class="myClass" type="text" id="selector">
    <input class="myClass" type="text" id="selector">

   $('input').keyup(function () {
        var key = this.value;
        $('.myClass').val(key);
    });
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/o8308q48/

Answer (score 0):

This works on Firefox.

On each paste event, we set the value of each input to this.value (this refers to the input where the paste event was done)

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length;i++){ 
    inputs[i].addEventListener("paste", function(){

        for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length;j++)
            inputs[j].value = this.value;
    }, false);
}
```

You could also use the keyup event and control when "control key", or "command" in osx, is pressed with "V" at the same time, but it would avoid when you do right click and click "paste" in the context menu. With the event paste you cover both ways.